# JS: remove all properties from an element

Tags: javascript

You know assigning a property to an element is very helpful and efficient during building. basically an element is an object which can be assigned to anything:

```js
let el = document.createElement('div');
el.a = 1;
el.b = [];
class C{}
el.c = new C()
```

and in testing these actually works well, solid results are returned;

```
console.log(el.a); // 1
```

I seek a way to watch in detail and manipulate these action.

for example, I want to get an object of all assigned values:

```
// something like
el.assigned // {a: 1, b: [], ...}
```

and a method to **delete all** (only the plugin javascript assigned, not the default such as `style`, `parentNode`, etc)

---

#### How I run into issue

> JsPlumb is a DOM element connectivity library archived by SVG, newest version 5.2.2 on Github, however not a browser release yet. currently stable version on [CDN JS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jsPlumb)

two APIs worth mentioning:

- `instance.connect`: create and return an instance object, meanwhile render SVG result to Dom.
- `jsPlumb.deleteConnection`, take a connection object as param and perform deletion.

But, the lib seems to use the element for caching in connect, and deleteConnection will not detach all reference completely, and the code will run into issue. which after deletion, we cannot connect anymore. In testing, with the help of @esqew, this is testified which a variable `_jsPlumbConnections` was assigned to element props, which the lib regards it as something still existing.

```js
// when you tries to connect again, the lib seems verifying through the assigned props and run into bug
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'x.endpoints[0]') jsPlumb.min.js
```

```js
this.plumb.bind('click', function(conn){
            connect.connections.splice(connect.connections.indexOf(conn.cn), 1);
            jsPlumb.deleteConnection(conn);
            console.log(Object.keys(conn.cn.source));
            attr_element({id: null, class: null}, conn.cn.source.backup);
            attr_element({id: null, class: null}, conn.cn.target.backup);
            connect.render();
        });
// ["_jsPlumbConnections"] (1)
```

Comment: What's the actual problem/question? What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I would strongly advice against adding props the elements,..  If you want to associate data with an element I would use a WeakMap..

Comment: if you do not agree with any of the question content or have any confusion, please send a comment

Comment: there are libs doing that, and by plugging in those libs would run my code into issue, I will add more detail into the question. I wonder if there is a generic way to detach all manually assigned props.

Comment: If you want to get your element's properties, you can spread it in an object. `{ ...el }`

Comment: `there are libs doing that,`  doesn't make it right.  For example, what if a lib your using adds `d`, and now using the accepted answer you end up deleting `d`.  But using a WeakMap means it's impossible for you to break another lib or another lib to break your code.  Or even in the future some props of Element might become Enumerable.  So, just be aware of potential dangers of your code breaking.  For me, a third party lib been able to break my code is something I try to avoid if at all possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't a good idea (as the comments on the OP stipulate), but you can probably get this done using the spread operator on an element created with `document.createElement`, which returns only the keys which you've added in this manner:

```js
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.a = 'foo';
element.b = 'bar';
element.c = 4;

console.log({...element});
```

You can then remove them all by iterating using `Object.keys()`:

```js
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.a = 'foo';
element.b = 'bar';
element.c = 4;
console.log({...element});

Object.keys(element).forEach(key => delete element[key]);
console.log({...element});
```

Comment: *"which returns only the keys which you've added in this manner"* That's not quite right. Property spread only takes own enumerable properties into account, but those could have been set in any number of ways. However, using this syntax to get such a list is unnecessary. You might as well just use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` or `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you were to open an issue on jsPlumb's Github for this. There is no mention of what the specific problem is but if there's a bug we'd like to know.

(edit)

is it this issue?

https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb/issues/1077

there is no bug with jsPlumb here. You are not calling delete from the instance that owns the connection.

Comment: thumbs up for solving the issue, thanks a lot.